# Custom validation method in Rails that receives whole hash of fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I need a custom validation method that receives all set fields. I need this because I dynamically add multiple fields for a `has_many :through` relation in a form and I need to make sure there aren't any duplicate values entered.

I know that regular Rails validation methods operate on a single field, but I couldn't find anything to handle all fields.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-each), you can do this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_each :name, :surname, :any_other_attributes, do |record, attr, value|
    ...
    # e.g. record.errors.add(attr, 'must start with upper case') if value =~ /\A[a-z]/
  end
end
```

Comment: And this still validates each record one by one, not as a whole.